# Position absolute. Force top : 0

Tags: css

I am implementing an image selector for a carousel :

[image]

The structure is the following :

- A `<div>` container with some horizontal padding to spare place for the chevrons.
- A `<div` for the chevron on the left with: `position : absolute; left:0;`
- A `<div` for the chevron on the right with: `position : absolute; right:0;`
- a `<div>` to contain the images with `white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden`

Problem : If I don't force `top:0` on the chevrons, I get this result :

[image]

Can someone explain why?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr40fk5v/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/EEE04A/ffffff?text=Image%201">
            </li><li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/5cb85c/ffffff?text=Image%202">
        </li><li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/5bc0de/ffffff?text=Image%203">
        </li><li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/f0ad4e/ffffff?text=Image%204">
        </li><li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/FF3167/ffffff?text=Image%205"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x100/cccccc/ffffff?text=<">
    </div>
    <div class="button-right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x100/cccccc/ffffff?text=>">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

.container {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.img-container {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.img-container li {
    display:inline-block;
}

.button-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    /* top: 0; */
}

.button-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    /* top: 0; */
}
```

Comment: A CSS3 alternative would be to apply `display: flex` to the main `.container` and the `ul`. No need for absolute positioning or inline-block.

Comment: @Michael_B That's neat. imo better that inline-block because it prevents the content from going to the next row when the page is not large enough.

Comment: You can learn more about flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Michael_B Very clear and complete, bookmarked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the other answers skirt around the real issue, which is that you have two stacked rows of content (the slides and, below them, the arrows). You could fix this with absolute positioning but I think it'd be much cleaner to just keep them in the same horizontal row to begin with. A simple example using `float`:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr40fk5v/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning doesn’t require a ‘relative’ element (as set on the .box element above). If you absolutely position an element without a positioning context, then the positioning will take place relative to the entire page. (The exception is if you don’t specify any top, bottom, left, or right values. In that case, even if there is no positioning context, the context will automatically become the immediate container element, and the element will still be in flow.)

So if you don't specify top or left position for some element with `position: absolute` they consider these position according to their normal position in DOM. Same is in your case they are taking top position from their normal position in DOM.
To place an element with position absolute we should provide these properties explicitly in most cases to avoid problems.

Answer (score 1):

You give the img-container `position:absolute;` and `width:450px;`

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style:none;
}

.container {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.img-container {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
}

.img-container li {
  display:inline-block;
}

.button-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /* top: 0; */
}

.button-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  /* top: 0; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/EEE04A/ffffff?text=Image%201">
      </li><li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/5cb85c/ffffff?text=Image%202">
      </li><li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/5bc0de/ffffff?text=Image%203">
      </li><li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/f0ad4e/ffffff?text=Image%204">
      </li><li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100/FF3167/ffffff?text=Image%205"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="button-left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x100/cccccc/ffffff?text=<">
  </div>
  <div class="button-right">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x100/cccccc/ffffff?text=>">
  </div>
</div>
```